# Access parent controller from sub ui-view component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, components

I can't seem to find an answer on this one, I've tried using require, but no luck It can't find the 'settings' parent from the component definition.

I want all of the 'child' routes to have access to all the 'settings' methods so I can re-use methods across multiple states.

How can I access methods on the 'settings' component controller, from a nested ui-view component?

index.html

`<ui-view></ui-view>`

app.js

```
$stateProvider.register('settings', {
    abstract : true,
    component: 'settings',
    url : '/settings'
});
$stateProvider.register('settings.user', {
    component: 'settingsUser',
    url : '/:user',
});

angular.module('app', [])
    .component('settings', {
        template : `<ui-view></ui-view>`,
        controller : class Settings {
            constructor($state) {
                this.test = () => console.log('test');
                $state.go('settings.user');
            }

        }
    })
    .component('settingsUser', {
         controller : class SettingsUser {
             constructor() {
                 // want to access parent controller methods
             }
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually quite simple, I just didn't expect it to work with routes, with the child view you can simply require the parent component through the [require block](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication). This exposes the controller of the required component in the $onInit life cycle phase in the child view's controller.

```
$stateProvider.register('settings', {
    abstract : true,
    component: 'settings',
    url : '/settings'
});
$stateProvider.register('settings.user', {
    component: 'settingsUser',
    url : '/:user',
});

angular.module('app', [])
    .component('settings', {
        template : `<ui-view></ui-view>`,
        controller : class Settings {
            constructor($state) {
                this.test = () => console.log('test');
                $state.go('settings.user');
            }

        }
    })
    .component('settingsUser', {
         require : {
             $settings : '^settings'
         },
         controller : class SettingsUser {
             constructor() {
                 // want to access parent controller methods
             }
             $onInit() {
                 this.$settings.test()
             }
         }
    });
```

Comment: But in this example you require all controoler not only one scope

Comment: This tells me you don't understand controllers and components, and not once did I ever mention scope, I mentioned the controller. A controller is a single instance and is (in components) and isolated scope so it is doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using a `$rootScope` instead `$scope` for what you access want.
in ths example `test1` is a `$rootscope` but `test2` is a `$scope`, in `controller Ctrl2` we change the `test1` and it will be changed in Ctrl1 see Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test1 = "topController";
    $scope.test2 = "topController2";
})
.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test1 = "mainController";
    $scope.test2 = "mainController2";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  {{test1}} {{test2}}
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  {{test1}} {{test2}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This make no sense?

Comment: `$rootScope` is a global scope

Comment: This goes against all angular principles... I've found a much nicer promoted solution by the Angular team which I've posted here

Comment: Share your solution please

Comment: I've just posted it